# Progress bar with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress-bar

I use the multiprocessing package to run the function: `run_performance`, on which it loads zip files in which they contains several csv files.

I search to display a progress bar properly with the number of csv in each zipfile.
With my code, the display is incoherent/wrong:

My code:

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

def get_filepaths(directory):
    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.
    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.
    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory.

def count_files_7z(myarchive):
   cnt_files = []
   with closing(ZipFile(myarchive)) as archive:
      for csv in archive.namelist():
         cnt_files.append(csv)
      return cnt_files

def run_performance(zipobj):
   zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zipobj)
   cnt = count_files_7z(zipobj)
   with alive_bar(len(cnt)) as bar:
      for f in zf.namelist():
         bar()
         with zf.open(f) as myfile:
            print(myfile) # and done other things

list_dir = "path_of_zipfiles" #

 for idx1, folder in enumerate(list_dir):
    get_all_zips = get_filepaths(folder)
    for idx2, zip_file in enumerate(get_all_zips):
       with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as zipobj:
          p = Process(target=run_performance,args=(zipobj.filename,))
          p.start()
     p.join()
```

My display:

```
|████▌                                   | ▄▆█ 1/9 [11%] in 0s (3.3/s, eta: 0s)|████▌                                   | ▄▆█ 1/9 [11%] in 0s (3.3/s, eta: 0s)|████▌                                   | ▄▆█ 1/9 [11%] in 0s (3.3/s, eta: 0s
...
```

If I place the line `p.join()` as the same indentation as `p.start()`, the display is correct, but the multiprocessing does not work anymore.
So the script takes too much time:

1m18s vs 0m14s

Desired output:

```
|████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [100%] in 2.4s (0.41/s)
|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [100%] in 4.7s (0.43/s)
|████████████████████                    | ▄▂▂ 1/2 [50%] in 2s (0.6/s, eta: 0s)
```

Comment: If you want to run multiple processes at the same time I would suggest using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) and calling `Pool.join()` instead of joining any of the processes individually.

Comment: I think I know what happens. Please put a `print()` before ` p.start()`.

Comment: please find: [root@vm-grafana bin]# time ./02-pickle-client.py

some spaces..














Loading csv files |████████████████████| 2/2 [100%] in 0.8s (2.41/s)
Loading csv files |████████████████████| 1/1 [100%] in 0.9s (1.09/s)
Loading csv files |████████████████████| 2/2 [100%] in 2.1s (0.96/s)

Comment: but the display should be better, just a lot space due to the print.. what append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few general comments concerning your code. In your main process you use a path to a file to open zip archive just to retrieve back the original file name. That really does not make too much sense. Then in `count_files_7z` you iterate the return value from `zf.namelist()` to build a list of the files within the archive when `zf.namelist()` is already a list of those files. That does not make too much sense either. You also use the context manager function `closing` to ensure that the archive is closed at the end of the block, but the `with` block itself is a context manager that serves the same purpose.

I tried installing **alive-progress** and the progress bars were a mess. This is a task better suited to multithreading rather than multiprocessing. Actually, it is probably better suited to serial processing since doing concurrent I/O operations to your disk, unless it is a solid state drive, is probably going to hurt performance. You will gain performance if there is heavy CPU-intensive processing involved of the files you read. If that is the case, I have passed to each thread a multiprocessing pool to which you can execute a calls to `apply` specifying functions in which you have placed CPU-intensive code. But the progress bars will should work better when done under multithreading rather than multiprocessing. Even then I could not get any sort of decent display with **alive-progress**, which admittedly I did not spend too much time on. So I have switched to using the more common **tqdm** module available from the **PyPi** repository.

Even with **tqdm** there is a problem in that when a progress bar reaches 100%, **tqdm** must be writing something (a newline?) that relocates the other progress bars. Therefore, what I have done is specified *leave=False*, which causes the bar to disappear when it reaches 100%. But at least you can see all the progress bars without distortion as they are progressing.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
from threading import Lock
import tqdm
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import heapq

def get_filepaths(directory):
    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.
    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.
    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory.


def get_free_position():
    """ Return the minimum possible position """
    with lock:
        free_position = heapq.heappop(free_positions)
    return free_position

def return_free_position(position):
    with lock:
        heapq.heappush(free_positions, position)

def run_performance(zip_file):
    position = get_free_position()
    with ZipFile(zip_file) as zf:
        file_list = zf.namelist()
        with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(file_list), position=position, leave=False) as bar:
            for f in file_list:
                with zf.open(f) as myfile:
                    ... # do things with myfile (perhaps myfile.read())
                    # for CPU-intensive tasks: result = pool.apply(some_function, args=(arg1, arg2, ... argn))
                    import time
                    time.sleep(.005) # simulate doing something
                bar.update()
    return_free_position(position)

def generate_zip_files():
    list_dir = ['path1', 'path2']
    for folder in list_dir:
        get_all_zips = get_filepaths(folder)
        for zip_file in get_all_zips:
            yield zip_file

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N_THREADS = 5
    free_positions = list(range(N_THREADS)) # already a heap
    lock = Lock()
    pool = Pool()
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(N_THREADS)
    for result in thread_pool.imap_unordered(run_performance, generate_zip_files()):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    thread_pool.close()
    thread_pool.join()
```

The code above uses a multiprocessing thread pool arbitrarily limited in size to 5 just as a demo. You can increase or decrease `N_THREADS` to whatever value you want, but as I said, it may or may not help performance. If you want one thread per zip file then:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_files = list(generate_zip_files())
    N_THREADS = len(zip_files)
    free_positions = list(range(N_THREADS)) # already a heap
    lock = Lock()
    pool = Pool()
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(N_THREADS)
    for result in thread_pool.imap_unordered(run_performance, zip_files):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    thread_pool.close()
    thread_pool.join()
```

Comment: Hi Booboo, thank you for explanation and new code. I need to adapt my code with yours. I will keep you inform asap

Comment: I got this error:   File "/opt/import2grafana/bin/libsgrafana.py", line 241, in get_free_position
    with lock:
NameError: name 'lock' is not defined

Comment: You didn't by chance modify the code did you, say for use with multiprocessing or some other change?

Comment: in fact, no i just modify the function def generate_zip_files(mypath):

Comment: I just try with your code. i need to modify yours, because, i need to filter in zip files. I don't need to read all

Comment: Well. `lock` if defined in the last code block I have that begins `if __name__ == '__main__':` and that makes it a global variable. So it should be visible as a global in all the other functions that are running in *the same process*. The code as published runs perfectly for me (I just have to add a further check as I walk the directory to only process files ending in '.zip', since I have other types of files in my directories).

Comment: You can see [here](http://pastie.org/p/67kDUmGKgJpqR7TAssUyIl) the actual code that runs with the added lines 13 and 14 to filter on zip files and with real paths specified on line 46. This link is only good for 24 hours (first time I am using this site for pasting code). You could paste your code on this or some other site, too, unless you see an error in what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @Booboo, i finally succeed with your code. I need to improve performance with pool.apply in the main function. Sorry for the delay, i develope when i got some time. In all case, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I meant `apply` rather than `submit`. I had it right in the code but for some reason wrong in the text (the method is `submit` if you are using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`).  So I have updated the text to change `submit` to `apply` just so it's less confusing. Anyway, I am happy it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `alive_bar` remembers the position of the cursor when it was called, and starts drawing the bar from that point. When you start many processes, each one is not aware of the other and the output gets scrambled.

Indeed, there is an open issue in github about this (see [here](https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress/issues/20)). There are some hacky solutions for using multithreading, but I don't think that it will be easy to solve it using multiprocessing, unless you implement some kind on interprocess communication that will slow down things.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) codebase there is an [example](https://github.com/Rockhopper-Technologies/enlighten/blob/master/examples/multiprocessing_queues.py) of something similar. You would just substitute the `process_files()` function with your own.

It's a bit large to recreate here, but the idea is you should really only be doing console output in the main process and use some form of IPC to relay the information from subprocesses. The Enlighten example uses queues for IPC, which is pretty reasonable given it's only sending it's current count.